# Sed - Conditional Matching of pattern

Tags: linux, sed

I want to do the following:

Find pattern 1, then find the first instance of pattern 2. After doing so, I want to print the next line. This is for a sed script. I'm pretty lost on how to do this, since sed doesn't have if statements.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add sample Inputs and sample outputs in code tags as per forum rules, keep learning !! thanks.

Comment: `since sed doesn't have if statements` but other tools like https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info do have control structures..

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/first/,${/second/{n;p;q}}' file
```

Set `-n` option to emulate grep i.e. only print what you want. Focus on the range from `first` to the end of the file (`$`). Then match `second` and get the next line (`n`), print (`p`) and quit (`q`).

Answer (score 0):

If filename **j.txt** contains below content:

```
10 20 30
40 50 60
10 90 80
```

`sed -n '/10/p' j.txt | sed -n '/20/,+1p'`

First it will search for pattern1 (*10*) and then it will search for pattern2 (*20*) and print corresponding next line with content match line

Output will be:

```
10 20 30
10 90 80
```